# Standard error of the population from a bootstrapped distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

I would like to compute the Std. Error (SE) of some statistic (lets call it *a*). Given than the distribution of *a* is usually not normal, I performed a bootstrap. I am not sure how to compute the SE from the bootstrapped empirical distribution. Is it the case that the SE would simply be equal to the Std. Deviation (SD)? Also, does it makes sense to rely on the SE if the empirical distribution is not normal?

Comment: Regardless of the distribution your mean will be normally distributed thanks to the CLT (most of the times). So a SE is appropriate since it regards the mean only and you can estimate is as the SD of the means.